# Gatt Null calling from another class in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello In the below code bluetooth gat value is coming when I am trying to call the method from another call.

```
List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
```

For the above line gattServices is getting Null .

Can any one help me how to use the gatt from method.

pesNative.java:

```
case  PesConstants.STATUS.AUTO_BRIGHTNESS:
                int auto_bright_value = jObj.optInt(Constant.VALUE);
                this.pesBleDevice.writeCommand(auto_bright_value);
                break;
```

pledevice.java:

```
 public void writeCommand(int auto_bright_value) {

        Log.d("jyothi", bluetoothGatt + "");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
        for (int i = 0; i < gattServices.size(); i++) {
            String serviceUUID = gattServices.get(i).getUuid().toString();
            if (serviceUUID.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_GUID)) {
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattServices.get(i).getCharacteristics();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                        gattCharacteristics) {
                    final String uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                    if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(TX_CHAR_GUID)) {
                        String jsonString = "{\"i\": 1, \"v\": 1, \"t\": 8, \"s\": \"dbri\", \"n\": " +auto_bright_value+"}";
                        Log.d("jsonstring",jsonString);
                        byte[] payload = jsonString.getBytes();
                        gattCharacteristic.setValue(payload);
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.i("jyothi", "jyothi:" + jsonString);
                        gattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                        boolean writeStatus = bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                        Log.i("mtu", "writeStatus:" + writeStatus);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the Client connected to the Server? Is the GATT service discovery complete?

Comment: @Risto yes the client connected and discovery the device